# How to Configure GZIP in IIS server?

Tags: iis, compression, gzip

We use IIS server and when I check for page speed, it tells me to compress js and css files in m.domainname.com (mobile domain). It is not saying files in main domain to compress.

I tried to add this code in web.config present inside m.domainname.com.

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

And I see no effect. Please help.

Comment: IIRC there's a feature you need to install in windows to enable the compression.

Comment: `IIRC -> If I Recall Correctly`. Look in the "Add features to Windows" dialogs for whatever version of Windows you are using.

Comment: If I had not installed that feature before, the page speed test would ask me to compress my js and css files from main site. But it didn't. Guess i have the feature installed already. Problem is coming form mobile domain only.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to use the **CompressedStaticFiles** middleware when serving compressed files over ASP.Net core. Make sure your build contains normals files and their compressed versions in order for the above middleware to work.

Place `app.UseCompressedStaticFiles();` instead of `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Startup.Configure()`.

This will ensure that you application will serve pre-compressed gzipped and brotli compressed files if the browser supports it.